# How to show in Django Admin Icons based on model value

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I need to show an Icon in Django Admin in the list and change view based on the value.

For example:

If Model Field `eventId` has value `1` then show icon (png or webfont)

Is this possible?

Model:

```py
class Events(models.Model):
    eventId = models.CharField(_('EventID'), max_length=254, null=False, blank=False, default='', )
    name = models.CharField(_('EventName'), max_length=254, null=False, blank=False, default='', )
    euuid = models.UUIDField(_('UUID'), default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(_('Created'), auto_now_add=True, blank=True, help_text=_('Date of the creation'))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on where you want to display the icon and can u share the admin and model code?

Comment: @AjayLingayat I updated my Question. The icon should be visible in the django admin backend on the list and change view of an object. (127.0.0.1:8000/admin).

Comment: You can add icons in `list_display` by creating a function that can return formatted html string to display icons based on values of a field.  you can refer https://realpython.com/customize-django-admin-python/#modifying-a-change-list-using-list_display  to learn how to customize admin templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your create a method like **icon()** and add this to list_display, fields and make it as readonly.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class EventsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    ...

    list_display = ['your_list_display_fields', 'icon']

    fields = ['your_model_fields_for_form', 'icon']

    readonly_fields = ['icon']

    def icon(self, obj):
        if obj.eventId == 1:
            icon_url = '<your_icon_url>'     # get icon url 
            return format_html('<img src="{}">', icon_url)
        return None
```